# Delete all nodes linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

In this function:

```
void final_delete(node **head) {
    node *tmp;

    tmp = *head;

    while (tmp != NULL) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
        free(*head);
        *head = tmp;
    }
    *head = tmp;             //<-------- HERE
}
```

Is the reported part necessary? `*head = tmp` isn't it already the last step of the `while` loop?

Comment: It's redundant.  Harmless, but serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the loop might not be iterated at all, in case that `tmp` is NULL.
In that case the last line ensures that `*head` is updated to NULL.
So your reason is not all of the explanation.
The last line only becomes unneeded because of your reason plus the fact that the loop only is never iterated if tmp became NULL via `*head` being NULL already, and THAT makes the last line unneeded.
It can be argued that the last line serves readability purposes, just make more obvious that `*head` gets updated, though much less obviously that it is updated to NULL. The readability would better be served by the last line being (unneeded and) and setting to NULL explicitly.

Comment: If clarity is needed, it is best served by replacing the assignment with an assertion.  Having the assignment is misleading, since it suggests that the two sides may not be equal.

Comment: @TomKarzes I like the assertion idea. I also like chqrlie  answer, which takes just a touch of more code-understanding (to find the loop condition) but then quite obviously visualises what the function ends in...

Answer (score 1):

Since you expect to delete the whole list, then *head should be a null pointer after the execution of the `final_delete()` function. Then you could just omit the `*head = tmp;` line and just add a line after the while loop with `*head = NULL;`. To answer your question, the last line is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is indeed redundant: `tmp` will be a null pointer at the end of the loop but either `*head` was already null before the loop or is was set to `NULL` during the last iteration of the loop.

Here is more readable version:

```c
void final_delete(node **head) {
    while (*head != NULL) {
        node *tmp = *head;
        *head = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```